# Javascript sort object by integer field

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects on which one of the fields is an integer value and i would like to sort using its field.

For example:

```
var myArray = {
    { name: "Robert", age: 47 },
    { name: "Carl", age: 22 },
    { name: "Ronaldo", age: 15 }
};

myArray.sort(function(a, b){ a.age - b.age });
```

The actual program run 24h and sort array every minute, sometimes it sorts correctly (no code changes), and sometimes (most of them) it does what appears to be random sort.

The desired output would be:

```
myArray = {
{ name: "Ronaldo", age: 15 },
{ name: "Carl", age: 22 },
{ name: "Robert", age: 47 }
}
```

but each time I run the code, it gives different orders as it wasn't sorting at all.

The real array has like 0-3000 entries and each object has a lot of properties. I don't know if it related to the size of the array or the data struct.

Already searched everywhere and everybody tells to pass a custom JS function to sort the array. This function would compare then with "ifs" or subtract them but I can't find anyone talking about this...

I tried wrap `a.age` and `b.age` into `parseInt()` 's and

```
myArray = myArray.sort(function(a, b){a.age - b.age});
```

Comment: I assume you have a typo since your array is defined with `{` and `}` and you have a simple mistake in the sort method which is causing the issue.

Comment: I just forgot to add the "return" in the function. As of the array, it is crated as object but I can iterate over it like that: for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) console.log(myArray[i])

Comment: It is not possible for it to be `{{},{},{}}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the value from your function.

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){ return a.age - b.age });
```

```js
const myArray = [{
    name: "Ronaldo",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Carl",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Robert",
    age: 47
  }
];

const sortedArray = myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.age - b.age
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: I forgot to add the return in the function here. But it was OK in the real code. Talking about the array. As you showed it seems like a array with just position zero which contains the "array object". Like in my code, the array was created using "{}" only, not putting every item inside "[]". But I can iterate over it with a simple for: for (var i= 0; i < length; i ++) console.log(myArray[i])